# postgresql/SQL database to kdb

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, kdb

For some reason scouring the internet still has not come up with an easy solution to import a sql database into kdb. I understand obdc can be used to do this but is there an easier way? Perhaps a pg_dump(although unsure how to import this into kdb) Another option maybe using sqlalchemy to grab tables in python and qpython to insert tables into kdb+ thoughts or ideas on what would be easiest?

Answer (score 1):

It is best that you use the Postgres COPY command, which can write directly into CSV file and then use kdb+'s CSV Import (0:) to import that file.

Here is a code snippet:

```
db-# create table test(cint int, cvarchar varchar(20), cdate timestamp);
db-# insert into test values (1, 'First String', '2017-06-20 13:34:21');
db-# insert into test values (2, 'Second String', '2017-06-20 13:35:25');
db-# copy test to '/tmp/test.csv' csv header;
```

And then from the q console:

```
q)test:("ISP";enlist ",") 0:`:/tmp/test.csv
q)test
cint cvarchar      cdate                        
------------------------------------------------
1    First String  2017.06.20D13:34:21.000000000
2    Second String 2017.06.20D13:35:25.000000000
```

Links:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html

http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#load-csv